# how to retrieve data from records in XML

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I have a XML:

```
<Name id="Name" dataType="java.lang.String" perDataProId="">Peter</Name>
 <Grid1 id="Grid1">
   <records>
     <record id="Grid1_0">
        <item id="department" dataType="java.lang.String" perDataProId="">PUR</item>
     </record>
    <record id="Grid1_1">
        <item id="department" dataType="java.lang.String" perDataProId="">SALE</item>
     </record>
   </records>
</Grid1>
```

I can get the Name tag text using:

```
if (dom.getElementsByTagName("Name").length!=0){
       name=  dom.getElementsByTagName("Name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;        
  }
```

but how to get the item department's value?
I have tried `dom.getElementsByTagName("Grid1_0").length` and the result is 0.
Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: you have a duplicate id in your code

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can get the element by id using getElementById, i.e.:

```js
dom.getElementById('Grid1_0')
```